# Added new Nameservers but domain name still 'parked'

Tags: dns, hosting, cpanel, whm, nameservers

I have created a new account on WHM and given it my domain name as the name. I then got the 2 name servers  used by every site on my WHM server and inserted them into the Nameserver fields on the my registrars site. Is that all I have to do?

I know it sometimes takes a while for the domain name to perpetrate but when I type in the url it says it still parked. Is this ok?

Comment: If you tell us the actual hostnames in question, we can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it seems what I've done is correct. The domain name did propagate eventually